# How can I swap labels and symbols in a legend in R?

Tags: r

The legend that R creates when you call `legend()` has the symbols (or line types etc) on the left and the labels on the right. I'd like it the other way round, i.e. labels on the left (right-aligned) and the symbols on the right.

I know that I can use `adj` to adjust the position of the labels, but with this they are not aligned properly anymore. If I set `adj=2` for example, the labels are to the left of the symbols, but the end of the text is not aligned with the symbols.

Any pointers on how to do this using either the standard `legend()` function or a package would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you set `trace = TRUE` and then save the output, you can draw the legend and then add the labels with a call to `text()` using the coordinates given by `trace`, setting `pos = 2` for right alignment. Here's an example:

```
    set.seed(1)
    plot(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),type='l',ylim=c(0,10),xlim=c(0,10),col=1)
    lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=2,lty=2)
    lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=3,lty=2)
    a <- legend(1,10,lty=1:3,col=1:3,legend=c("","",""),bty="n",trace=TRUE)
    text(a$text$x-1,a$text$y,c("line 1","line 2","line 3"),pos=2)
```

[image]