# How to put legend marker on the right side of the word in R plot

Tags: r, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I swap labels and symbols in a legend in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366800/how-can-i-swap-labels-and-symbols-in-a-legend-in-r)

With the following code:

```
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
trucks <- c(2, 5, 4, 5, 12)
g_range <- range(0, cars, trucks)
plot(cars, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range,  axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
legend(1, g_range[2], c("cars","trucks"), cex=0.8,  col=c("blue","red"), pch=21:22, lty=1:2);
```

How can I modify the code such that the legend marker (i.e. -o- and -box- sign) are placed on the ***right*** side of their corresponding name?