# How to make labels in the legend align right in R?

Tags: r, plot, alignment, legend

[image]

As this picture shows, how can I make these labels align right?

I am using legend in R.

Comment: Or make the lines (with colors ) to the right of the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `?legend`

```
## right-justifying a set of labels: thanks to Uwe Ligges
x <- 1:5; y1 <- 1/x; y2 <- 2/x
plot(rep(x, 2), c(y1, y2), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
lines(x, y1); lines(x, y2, lty = 2)
temp <- legend("topright", legend = c(" ", " "),
           text.width = strwidth("1,000,000"),
           lty = 1:2, xjust = 1, yjust = 1,
           title = "Line Types")
text(temp$rect$left + temp$rect$w, temp$text$y,
     c("1,000", "1,000,000"), pos = 2)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I can't find a way to automatically align the legend with the lines on the right.  But you may be able to produce a legend using `text` placement and option `bty="n"` to remove the border.

```
## similar to above
x <- 1:5; y1 <- 1/x; y2 <- 2/x
plot(rep(x, 2), c(y1, y2), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
lines(x, y1); lines(x, y2, lty = 2)
temp <- legend("topright", legend = c(" ", " "),
           text.width = strwidth("1,000,000"),
           lty = 1:2, xjust = 1, yjust = 1, bty="n")

text(4, 2,"lbl1")
text(3.9, 1.92,"mylbl2")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, in legend, can I make all the labels align right? In your example, "1000" and "1000000" are align right, however, their corresponding lines are still align left, can we make both align right? Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Or can I make the the lines to the right of the text?

Comment: I solved my problem referring to your code, Thanks!!

Comment: Excellent!  Glad you got it sorted

Comment: Another useful question here on using the command "trace" to help you place the text appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366800/how-can-i-swap-labels-and-symbols-in-a-legend-in-r