# How do I right-align text and symbols in my legend box

Tags: r, plot, graph, legend, legend-properties

... when specifying "topright" & put symbols on right side of legend rather than to the left of the labels.

Basically I want my legend to be in a box on the top right corner of my plot, and have all my text right-aligned, not left aligned.

My code is in a loop and applied to over 100 graphs, so I'm trying to keep the legend in the same spot in each graph.

I tried using `just` and `adj` which did not work for me.

```
legend("topright", legend=c("data", "data", "data", "data", "data",
                "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data"),
        ncol = 1,
        lty = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
        pch = c(NA, sym[1], sym[2], sym[2], sym[3], 19, 17, 15, 19, 17, 15), 
        col = c(blue, aa, aa, aa, aa, gr, bl, pu, gr, bl, pu),
        pt.bg = c(NA, a, b, c, d, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        pt.cex = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, .5, .5, .5, .5, .5, .5),
        cex = .75, 
        lwd = c(2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        text.col = "black")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make labels in the legend align right in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031530/how-to-make-labels-in-the-legend-align-right-in-r)

Comment: I've tried adj as well, but the result is that although text is right-aligned, all the text in the legend moves to the center as if i selected "center" instead of "topright." It also moves out of the box which stays on the "topright." The symbols also stay on the "topright." It also doesn't switch the position of the symbols and the text.

Answer (score 1):

Example from `?legend`

```
## right-justifying a set of labels: thanks to Uwe Ligges
x <- 1:5; y1 <- 1/x; y2 <- 2/x
plot(rep(x, 2), c(y1, y2), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
lines(x, y1); lines(x, y2, lty = 2)
temp <- legend("topright", legend = c(" ", " "),
               text.width = strwidth("1,000,000"),
               lty = 1:2, xjust = 1, yjust = 1,
               title = "Line Types")
text(temp$rect$left + temp$rect$w, temp$text$y,
     c("1,000", "1,000,000"), pos = 2)
```

Comment: This works, except the symbols are still on the left side of the text. I'm still having trouble resolving this particular issue.

Comment: Do you want the labels on the left side and the lines on the right side?

Comment: Yes - the labels on the left side and lines/symbols on the right side.