# Legend for line type (or marker) and for colour in base R plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have a graph for which I have several colours and several line types. And they are crossed, e.g. dashed line is blue or green. I want a legend using basic plot in R that will be in a square/rectangle where rows are colours and columns are line types.

UPDATE:

With the help of the answer by @G. Grothendieck, I have understood how to get two columns but the labels are still not arranged in the way I intend. Using this [answer on placing labels to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366800/how-can-i-swap-labels-and-symbols-in-a-legend-in-r/9367021#9367021), I figured out how to get the labels to appear to the left of the symbol (although I feel it is a laborious to get there and it should be simpler). I've used the stub of that answer and the one I got here to create this example.

```
set.seed(1)
plot(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),type='l',ylim=c(0,15),xlim=c(0,10),col=1)
lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=1,lty="dashed")
lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=2,lty="solid")
lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=2,lty="dashed")
lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=3,lty="solid")
lines(1:10,runif(min=0,max=10,10),col=3,lty="dashed")
#draw the legend lines
a <- legend(1,14,lty=rep(ltys, each = (nr)),col=1:3,legend=rep("",6),bty="n", ncol=nc,
        trace=TRUE)
#place text labels one value to the left of the legend lines for only the first column
text(a$text$x[1:3]-1,a$text$y[1:3],Vars,pos=2)
#place a text label above the legend lines for the second attribute to define in legend
text(a$text$x[c(1,4)]-1.5, 14, c("Young", "Old"), pos=4)
```

[image]

Is there something simpler or is this the best R can give me?

Comment: If you get desperate, you could always just use `text` and `segments` to create the legend yourself.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Here the first row is black and the second row is red and the third row is green. The first column is solid and the second is dashed.  We use title= to provide the headings of the columns.  This will require a bit of trial and error to get the positioning right.  See (2) for an alternative.

```
nc <- 2   
Vars <- c("VarA", "VarB", "VarC")
nr <- length(Vars)

plot(0)
legend("topleft", rep(Vars, nc), col = 1:nr, 
   lty = rep(1:nc, each = nr), ncol = nc, cex = 0.8, 
   title = "        Young              Old")
```

[image: screenshot]

**2)** This is similar but we add a row with no lines to serve as the headings avoiding the tedious trial and error with the `title` approach.

```
nc <- 2   
Vars <- c("VarA", "VarB", "VarC")
nr <- length(Vars)

plot(0)
legend("topleft", c("Young", Vars, "Old", Vars), col = 0:nr, 
   lty = 0:nr, ncol = nc, cex = 0.8)
```

Comment: Can I get it so that there is a label above the solid lines ("mean) and another above the dashed ("sd")?

Comment: Have added two approaches to the column headings.