# How to shift one specific legend label with subscript slightly downwards?

Tags: r, plot, legend, subscript

I've generated a subscript in a legend label with `expression()` that shifts the entire label slightly upward and looks lousy (the red one in the middle).

```
plot(1:10, type="l")
curve(x^2, col=2, add=TRUE)
curve(x^3, col=3, add=TRUE)
legend("bottomright", lty=1, col=3:1,
       legend=c(expression(z>2),
                expression(z==italic(z[1])), 
                expression(z==0)))
```

[image]

With help of [this great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367021/6574038) I get what I want by multiplying the `y`-location of the specific label, figuring out the right number of spaces of the `legend` text, and shifting the `x`-values, by values that I've laboriously diced.

```
a <- legend("bottomright", lty=1, col=3:1, trace=T, 
            legend=rep("         ", 3))
a$text$y[2] <-  a$text$y[2]/1.043
text(a$text$x-.3, a$text$y, c(expression(z>2),
                              expression(z==italic(z[1])), 
                              expression(z==0)), pos=4)
```

However, it could become quite a hobby to figure out the right values, and it might not be reliable when sending the plot to a device (e.g. `pdf`), because `plot` outputs, e.g. by `pdf` are dynamic (consider various `layout`s or `pdf` sizes).

The cause is indeed the `expression()`, since

```
mean(a$text$y[-2]) == a$text$y[2]
# [1] TRUE
```

I didn't find an option such as `legend.txt.y=c(1, 1.043, 1)`, and the `x` and `y` seem to only accept scalars. And the question is still open how much exactly a subscripted label is shifted.

**Might there be option I've overlooked or any solution to shift the `expression()` slightly downwards by a factor or something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ultimate goal is just to have legend entries evenly spaced you could consider using `phantom()` on each element in the legend so that an equal amount of space is reserved but nothing is drawn.  This sidesteps the need to calculate the adjustment although it does create a small amount of whitespace on the right side of the legend. In this case each element is having 'i<sub>1</sub>' invisibly appended (as you don't seem to be able to generate subscripts in plotmath without it being next to something).

```
plot(1:10, type="l")
curve(x^2, col=2, add=TRUE)
curve(x^3, col=3, add=TRUE)
legend("bottomright", lty=1, col=3:1,
       legend=c(expression(z>2*phantom(i[1]),
                           z==italic(z[1])*phantom(i[1]),
                           z==0*phantom(i[1]))))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an elegant answer, but it works. The `legend` function is written in base R. Within it is defined another function called `text2` which among the `...` parameters passed to it from the main function has one called `adj` that takes only a single (x, y) vector. `text2` writes all the labels using only this single parameter, so I don't think the adjustment you are talking about is possible using the function `legend` without some kind of hack or workaround.

*However...*

You *could* copy the function and modify it so that it takes a *list* of vectors and loops through them, one for each label. Say you call it `legend2`. Then it would work like this:

```r
plot(1:10, type="l")
curve(x^2, col=2, add=TRUE)
curve(x^3, col=3, add=TRUE)
legend2("bottomright", lty=1, col=3:1,
       legend=c(expression(z>2),
                expression(z==z[1]),
                expression(z==0)),
        adj = list(c(0, 0.5), c(0, 0.7), c(0, 0.5))) # Note second element shifted down
```

To give this:[image]

Here is the modified function:

```r
legend2 <- function (x, y = NULL, legend, fill = NULL, col = par("col"), 
    border = "black", lty, lwd, pch, angle = 45, density = NULL, 
    bty = "o", bg = par("bg"), box.lwd = par("lwd"), box.lty = par("lty"), 
    box.col = par("fg"), pt.bg = NA, cex = 1, pt.cex = cex, pt.lwd = lwd, 
    xjust = 0, yjust = 1, x.intersp = 1, y.intersp = 1, adj = lapply(1:length(x), 
      function(vec) c(0, 0.5)),  text.width = NULL, 
    text.col = par("col"), text.font = NULL, 
    merge = do.lines && has.pch, trace = FALSE, plot = TRUE, 
    ncol = 1, horiz = FALSE, title = NULL, inset = 0, xpd, title.col = text.col, 
    title.adj = 0.5, seg.len = 2) 
{
    if (missing(legend) && !missing(y) && (is.character(y) || 
        is.expression(y))) {
        legend <- y
        y <- NULL
    }
    mfill <- !missing(fill) || !missing(density)
    if (!missing(xpd)) {
        op <- par("xpd")
        on.exit(par(xpd = op))
        par(xpd = xpd)
    }
    title <- as.graphicsAnnot(title)
    if (length(title) > 1) 
        stop("invalid 'title'")
    legend <- as.graphicsAnnot(legend)
    n.leg <- if (is.call(legend)) 
        1
    else length(legend)
    if (n.leg == 0) 
        stop("'legend' is of length 0")
    auto <- if (is.character(x)) 
        match.arg(x, c("bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", 
            "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right", "center"))
    else NA
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        xy <- xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE)
        x <- xy$x
        y <- xy$y
        nx <- length(x)
        if (nx < 1 || nx > 2) 
            stop("invalid coordinate lengths")
    }
    else nx <- 0
    xlog <- par("xlog")
    ylog <- par("ylog")
    rect2 <- function(left, top, dx, dy, density = NULL, angle, 
        ...) {
        r <- left + dx
        if (xlog) {
            left <- 10^left
            r <- 10^r
        }
        b <- top - dy
        if (ylog) {
            top <- 10^top
            b <- 10^b
        }
        rect(left, top, r, b, angle = angle, density = density, 
            ...)
    }
    segments2 <- function(x1, y1, dx, dy, ...) {
        x2 <- x1 + dx
        if (xlog) {
            x1 <- 10^x1
            x2 <- 10^x2
        }
        y2 <- y1 + dy
        if (ylog) {
            y1 <- 10^y1
            y2 <- 10^y2
        }
        segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
    }
    points2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog) 
            y <- 10^y
        points(x, y, ...)
    }
    text2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog) 
            y <- 10^y
        text(x, y, ...)
    }
    if (trace) 
        catn <- function(...) do.call("cat", c(lapply(list(...), 
            formatC), list("\n")))
    cin <- par("cin")
    Cex <- cex * par("cex")
    if (is.null(text.width)) 
        text.width <- max(abs(strwidth(legend, units = "user", 
            cex = cex, font = text.font)))
    else if (!is.numeric(text.width) || text.width < 0) 
        stop("'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0")
    xc <- Cex * xinch(cin[1L], warn.log = FALSE)
    yc <- Cex * yinch(cin[2L], warn.log = FALSE)
    if (xc < 0) 
        text.width <- -text.width
    xchar <- xc
    xextra <- 0
    yextra <- yc * (y.intersp - 1)
    ymax <- yc * max(1, strheight(legend, units = "user", cex = cex)/yc)
    ychar <- yextra + ymax
    if (trace) 
        catn("  xchar=", xchar, "; (yextra,ychar)=", c(yextra, 
            ychar))
    if (mfill) {
        xbox <- xc * 0.8
        ybox <- yc * 0.5
        dx.fill <- xbox
    }
    do.lines <- (!missing(lty) && (is.character(lty) || any(lty > 
        0))) || !missing(lwd)
    n.legpercol <- if (horiz) {
        if (ncol != 1) 
            warning(gettextf("horizontal specification overrides: Number of columns := %d", 
                n.leg), domain = NA)
        ncol <- n.leg
        1
    }
    else ceiling(n.leg/ncol)
    has.pch <- !missing(pch) && length(pch) > 0
    if (do.lines) {
        x.off <- if (merge) 
            -0.7
        else 0
    }
    else if (merge) 
        warning("'merge = TRUE' has no effect when no line segments are drawn")
    if (has.pch) {
        if (is.character(pch) && !is.na(pch[1L]) && nchar(pch[1L], 
            type = "c") > 1) {
            if (length(pch) > 1) 
                warning("not using pch[2..] since pch[1L] has multiple chars")
            np <- nchar(pch[1L], type = "c")
            pch <- substr(rep.int(pch[1L], np), 1L:np, 1L:np)
        }
        if (!is.character(pch)) 
            pch <- as.integer(pch)
    }
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- log10(x)
        if (ylog) 
            y <- log10(y)
    }
    if (nx == 2) {
        x <- sort(x)
        y <- sort(y)
        left <- x[1L]
        top <- y[2L]
        w <- diff(x)
        h <- diff(y)
        w0 <- w/ncol
        x <- mean(x)
        y <- mean(y)
        if (missing(xjust)) 
            xjust <- 0.5
        if (missing(yjust)) 
            yjust <- 0.5
    }
    else {
        h <- (n.legpercol + !is.null(title)) * ychar + yc
        w0 <- text.width + (x.intersp + 1) * xchar
        if (mfill) 
            w0 <- w0 + dx.fill
        if (do.lines) 
            w0 <- w0 + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
        w <- ncol * w0 + 0.5 * xchar
        if (!is.null(title) && (abs(tw <- strwidth(title, units = "user", 
            cex = cex) + 0.5 * xchar)) > abs(w)) {
            xextra <- (tw - w)/2
            w <- tw
        }
        if (is.na(auto)) {
            left <- x - xjust * w
            top <- y + (1 - yjust) * h
        }
        else {
            usr <- par("usr")
            inset <- rep_len(inset, 2)
            insetx <- inset[1L] * (usr[2L] - usr[1L])
            left <- switch(auto, bottomright = , topright = , 
                right = usr[2L] - w - insetx, bottomleft = , 
                left = , topleft = usr[1L] + insetx, bottom = , 
                top = , center = (usr[1L] + usr[2L] - w)/2)
            insety <- inset[2L] * (usr[4L] - usr[3L])
            top <- switch(auto, bottomright = , bottom = , bottomleft = usr[3L] + 
                h + insety, topleft = , top = , topright = usr[4L] - 
                insety, left = , right = , center = (usr[3L] + 
                usr[4L] + h)/2)
        }
    }
    if (plot && bty != "n") {
        if (trace) 
            catn("  rect2(", left, ",", top, ", w=", w, ", h=", 
                h, ", ...)", sep = "")
        rect2(left, top, dx = w, dy = h, col = bg, density = NULL, 
            lwd = box.lwd, lty = box.lty, border = box.col)
    }
    xt <- left + xchar + xextra + (w0 * rep.int(0:(ncol - 1), 
        rep.int(n.legpercol, ncol)))[1L:n.leg]
    yt <- top - 0.5 * yextra - ymax - (rep.int(1L:n.legpercol, 
        ncol)[1L:n.leg] - 1 + !is.null(title)) * ychar
    if (mfill) {
        if (plot) {
            if (!is.null(fill)) 
                fill <- rep_len(fill, n.leg)
            rect2(left = xt, top = yt + ybox/2, dx = xbox, dy = ybox, 
                col = fill, density = density, angle = angle, 
                border = border)
        }
        xt <- xt + dx.fill
    }
    if (plot && (has.pch || do.lines)) 
        col <- rep_len(col, n.leg)
    if (missing(lwd) || is.null(lwd)) 
        lwd <- par("lwd")
    if (do.lines) {
        if (missing(lty) || is.null(lty)) 
            lty <- 1
        lty <- rep_len(lty, n.leg)
        lwd <- rep_len(lwd, n.leg)
        ok.l <- !is.na(lty) & (is.character(lty) | lty > 0) & 
            !is.na(lwd)
        if (trace) 
            catn("  segments2(", xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, ",", 
                yt[ok.l], ", dx=", seg.len * xchar, ", dy=0, ...)")
        if (plot) 
            segments2(xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, yt[ok.l], dx = seg.len * 
                xchar, dy = 0, lty = lty[ok.l], lwd = lwd[ok.l], 
                col = col[ok.l])
        xt <- xt + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
    }
    if (has.pch) {
        pch <- rep_len(pch, n.leg)
        pt.bg <- rep_len(pt.bg, n.leg)
        pt.cex <- rep_len(pt.cex, n.leg)
        pt.lwd <- rep_len(pt.lwd, n.leg)
        ok <- !is.na(pch)
        if (!is.character(pch)) {
            ok <- ok & (pch >= 0 | pch <= -32)
        }
        else {
            ok <- ok & nzchar(pch)
        }
        x1 <- (if (merge && do.lines) 
            xt - (seg.len/2) * xchar
        else xt)[ok]
        y1 <- yt[ok]
        if (trace) 
            catn("  points2(", x1, ",", y1, ", pch=", pch[ok], 
                ", ...)")
        if (plot) 
            points2(x1, y1, pch = pch[ok], col = col[ok], cex = pt.cex[ok], 
                bg = pt.bg[ok], lwd = pt.lwd[ok])
    }
    xt <- xt + x.intersp * xchar
    if (plot) {
        if (!is.null(title)) 
            text2(left + w * title.adj, top - ymax, labels = title, 
                adj = c(title.adj, 0), cex = cex, col = title.col)
        for(i in 1:length(xt))
        {
        text2(xt[i], yt[i], labels = legend[i], adj = adj[[i]], cex = cex, 
            col = text.col, font = text.font)
            }
    }
    invisible(list(rect = list(w = w, h = h, left = left, top = top), 
        text = list(x = xt, y = yt)))
}
```